# How can I test if a page object yml file has orphaned keys using rspec?

Tags: page-objects, ruby, rspec

I like using page objects through a yaml file with name:locator pairs

One problem I run into is that over time as the locators file grows, test cases are changed or removed and we end up with duplicates and orphans.

Is there any way to test if page objects stored this way are being used or are orphans through automated testing ?

Comment: A reminder to downvoters that self-answered questions are not only allowed, but encouraged! Experts who run into problems and then shares how they're solved is a good thing!

Answer (score 1):

You can write an RSpec test that tries to do this by grepping spec files for the locator names.  It will not be foolproof.  Some orphans might slip through and the test still passes (falsely).  However if the locator is not found anywhere it does indicate an orphan and it will fail the test.

This is based on:

- locators being in a `locators.yml` file
- locator file format is `name : 'locator_string'` per line
- spec file having the format `*_spec.rb`
- specs in subdirectories are supported (through `glob`)

  ```
  require 'rspec'

  describe 'Page Objects locator yml file' do

    it "uses all its locator keys" do
      locators_file = File.open('locators.yml')
      pairs = []
      keys = []

      locators_file.each_line do |line|
        words = line.split(': ')
        pairs << {words[0] => words[1]}
        keys << words[0]
      end
      locators_file.close

      files = Dir.glob("**/*_spec.rb")
      unused_keys = []
      keys.each do |key|
        @key_used = false
        files.each {|file| search_file_for_key(file, key) }
        unused_keys << key unless @key_used
      end
      unused_keys_exist = unused_keys.size > 0
      if unused_keys_exist
        p "Unused Page Object keys! Please address these orphans:"
        p unused_keys
      end

      expect(unused_keys_exist).not_to be, 
        lambda {"Failure - orphan page object identifiers #{unused_keys}"}    
    end

    def search_file_for_key(file, key)
      spec_file = File.open(file)
      file_contents = spec_file.read
      spec_file.close
      @key_used = true if file_contents.match(/#{key}/)
    end

  end
  ```